# Dirac operator: Hermitian or antiHermitian parts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, linear-algebra, majorana-fermions

We know that
$i \partial_t$ and $-i \partial_x$ are both Hermitian operators.

If I understand correctly the Dirac operator
$$
i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu
$$
contains the $\gamma^\mu$ such that

1. in the Minkowski signature, we have the $\gamma^0$ Hermitian, while the $\gamma^1$,$\gamma^2$,$\gamma^3$ antiHermitian.
2. in the Euclidean signature, we have the $\gamma^0$, $\gamma^1$,$\gamma^2$,$\gamma^3$ all Hermitian.

e.g., these seem independent fact regardless Dirac, Weyl or Majorana basis of $\gamma^\mu$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices

In other words, **my question is that WHY:**

- $i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ contains Hermitian or antiHermitian parts in Minkowski signature (?).
- $i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ contains only Hermitian parts for Euclidean signature (?).

If we only have physical eigenvalues to be real, should the full operators be Hermitian?

Or is that we actually $i \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ demand as a Hermitian operator not $i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$?

Comment: First, your gamma Minkowskian $\gamma$'s may have the opposite hermiticity depending upon your metric signature.  Second..I believe your last line nails it, that's why we define the adjoint of the Dirac equation the way we do.